# Problem with a variable not changing value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables

So I have one problem with my code, which is that one variable is not working as it's supposed to do. Here are the codes I'm using:

```
format long
f = inline('-x.^2');
for i = 0:10
    [I(i+1) h(i+1) tid(i+1)] = trapets(f,0,1,2^i);
end

for i = 0:10
    trunk(i+1) = I(i+1) - log(2);
end

hold on
grid on
plot(log(h),log(trunk),'r+')

t = -7:0;
c = polyfit(log(h),log(trunk),1);
yy = polyval(c,t);
plot(t,yy)
grid off
hold off

koefficienter = real(c)
```

and also this:

```
function [ I,h,tid ] = trapets(f,a,b,n )
h=(b-a)/n;

tic;
I=(f(a)+f(b));
for k=2:2:n-2
    I = I+2*f(a+k*h);
end

for k = 1:2:n-1
    I = I + 4*f(a+k*h);
end

I = I * h/3;
tid = toc;
end
```

So the problem here is that the variable `I` is not changing value. It gets 11 values when I run the first code (I don't run the last code I wrote, it's only used by the first one), but the values are all the same. I don't know if the problem is that the variable `n`, which I use in the the second code, never change value, although I'm trying to do that with the "2^i" part in "trapets(f,0,1,2^i)". If the case is that `n` never change value, is there a solution to do that?

And if the problem is not the variable `n`, why doesn't the variable `I` change value in the code?

Comment: @nisse: Here's a general tip: Do not name your variables as `l` or `l1`, `l2`, etc. It's really hard to distinguish it from `I` or `1` in certain fonts.

Comment: Okay, thanks. As a clerification: k = 1:2:n-1 in the second code it says n-1, as the number one and not the variable 'I'.

Comment: @yoda I didn't make any variable changes.

Comment: okay, so what did just happen?

Comment: @trutheality: I apologize, it was my mistake... I saw the comparison and this is what I saw everywhere: http://imgur.com/a/iD1OR (the top being the original and the bottom being your edit) and thought you had changed it from `l` to `I`, when it actually was the difference between normal font and monospaced font. This fumble on my part only further reinforces my first comment to the OP!

Comment: Thanks for the edit trutheality. Anyone got the answer to the problem? I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

After running your program I found out the `I` always equals `-1/h` after the for loops, which makes `I = I * h/3;` always give you the same result.

Comment: Okay, I just found out that I get different values for 'I' if i change the function to something with a higher power. Thanks for all the help anyway.